# Jbutton to select and display an array item

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hey guys I have a real simple program I want to make.

One button that when clicked will display an item from an array list.  What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want a specific item from an array or a random?

Answer (score 1):

Create a jButton. Add a Actionlistener to the button. In the actionlistener method create a loop that will go through all the data in array list and print it in screen or wherever you want.